# How to get speciefic properties from GET response(array)

Tags: angular, get

I have this GET array response from an API and I want to loop through it:

```js
[
  {
   "Version":1,
    "Key":"215854",
    "Type":"City",
     "Rank":31,
     "LocalizedName":"Tel Aviv",
      "Country":{
            "ID":"IL",
            "LocalizedName":"Israel"
        },
        "AdministrativeArea":{
            "ID":"TA",
             "LocalizedName":"Tel Aviv"
        }
   }
]
```

and I want to get the exact properties as my interface:

```js
export interface citySearch
    {
    Key:String,
    LocalizeName:String,
    Country:{
        LocalizeName:String
        }   
    }
```

**Service**

```js
import {citySearch} from '../interfaces/citySearch.model'


export class WeatherService {



  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  getLocation(query:String):Observable<citySearch>{
    return this.http.get<citySearch>(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/autocomplete?apikey=${this.apikey}&q=${query}&language=en-us`)
.pipe(
      map((receivedData:citySearch)=>{
        return receivedData
      }
    ))
  }
}
```

**Component.ts**

```js
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  citySearch!: citySearch;

  constructor(public weatherService:WeatherService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.weatherService.getLocation("tel aviv").subscribe((data:citySearch)=>{
      this.citySearch = data
      console.log("this.citySearch:", this.citySearch);
    })
  }


}
```

How do I map through the response to get the speciefic properties of the interface?

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried and what is the issue of the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

```js
import {citySearch} from '../interfaces/citySearch.model'


export class WeatherService {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  getLocation(query:String):Observable<citySearch>{
    return this.http.get<citySearch>(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/autocomplete?apikey=${this.apikey}&q=${query}&language=en-us`)
.pipe(
      map(items => items.map({Key, LocalizeName, Country }:citySearch) => {
        return {Key, LocalizeName, Country: {LocalizeName: Country. LocalizedName}};
      }
    )))
  }
}
```

In your map function you can map each item, Remember the map fn from rx/js is not same as javascript Array.map

Read more on rxjs.map

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map